# How to check list size in Android

Tags: android, list, arraylist

I want get list data from server and show it into my application, for get list data I write below codes in **`Adapter`** :

```
    if (model.get(position).getAwards() != null || model.get(position).getAwards().size() > 0) {
        int wonTimes = model.get(position).getAwards().get(0).getWonTimes();
        int nominatedTimes = model.get(position).getAwards().get(0).getNominatedTimes();
```

But when running application show me this **error** :

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
```

And show this error to this lines :

```
        int wonTimes = model.get(position).getAwards().get(0).getWonTimes();
        int nominatedTimes = model.get(position).getAwards().get(0).getNominatedTimes();
```

my award filed from json :

```
"award": [],
```

Before set award's item into `int` value, I check list size.
Why run application show me error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of || add && it will work fine

like

```
if (model.get(position).getAwards() != null && model.get(position).getAwards().size() > 0)
```

Comment: thanks my friend, it work to me. can you say me what is deference of || and && ? can you say my my friend?

Comment: If you use ||, if the first item is true it will go inside the condition, it will not check the second condition.